# Are there any Laravel Profilers that work with JSON APIs?

Tags: laravel

I've seen barryvdh's debugbar, but it seems to only work when you're serving pages. Every single response from my site is `application/json`.

Is there some hidden option I'm missing in barryvdh's bar or is there another option for Profiling my L4 app?

I'm not asking for ranking or opinions, just a link to *any* profiler that can just dump results to an Array or log file.

Comment: Have you ever used [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/)? It has a pretty handy [profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Answer (score 5):

So, I was frustrated with the solution I described earlier and went ahead and created a fork of laravel-debugbar that did exactly what I was looking for:

https://github.com/Dukeman330/laravel-debugbar

Basically I bolted on a "debugbar" route, controller, and view that opens a full-screen version of the debugbar, making it easy to walk through the debug files output by ajax queries. If you want to give this a shot, update your composer.json as follows:

```
"repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Dukeman330/laravel-debugbar.git"
}],
"require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "dev-master"
},
```

Then, make your ajax calls as you normally would and to see the output, navigate to `[your-site]/debugbar` in a browser.

---

**Previous Answer:**

This isn't exactly an ideal solution, but I've been working around the same issue by setting up a little 'profiler' page that renders my JSON output with the profiler bar.  I created a `profiler.blade.php` with the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>{{json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)}}</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, any time I want to profile a function I'm building, rather than `return $output;` I run something like:

`return \View::make('profiler', ['data' => $output]);`

Again, not ideal since the thing calling your rest API won't know how to handle this output, but it works pretty well if you're developing the API in a browser.

Comment: @chris-garson I did exactly what you mention, and I see debugbar working on usual pages, but I can't visit /debugbar page, because in your package required controller not exists. It's exists only in your repository, could you please update your answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can Use

```
print_r($response);
```

instead of

```
return response()->json($response); //comment it
```

and open it in a browser (for get requests);

**It's important you don't return anything**

Answer (score 1):

As per the above answers **Laravel Debug Bar cannot we used in rest api profiling** , the alternative which i stumbled upon is above Package:

> [Packagist url](https://packagist.org/packages/jkocik/laravel-profiler)
>
> [Git Url](https://github.com/jkocik/laravel-profiler)

Installation procedure:

- Step 1: Install Profiler Package Requirements: PHP 7.1+ and Laravel
  5.2+

  It is recommended to install Profiler Package only for development

> composer require jkocik/laravel-profiler --dev

- Step 2: Publish configuration file
  Run command

> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\ServiceProvider"

... and check config/profiler.php file for Profiler settings.

-Step 3: Install Profiler Server and Profiler Client
It is recommended to install Profiler Server and Profiler Client only for development

> npm install laravel-profiler-client --save-dev

- Step 4: Run Profiler Server and Profiler Client
  Windows users: If you have any issue with running Profiler Server or Profiler Client check Installation options / issues section below.

Run command

> php artisan profiler:server

Dashboard View of this package :

[image: Dashboard View]

Hope this would solve your problem !!

Answer (score 1):

The MIT-licensed [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) is gaining steam as a Debug Bar alternative.

Like Laravel Debug Bar, it collects and displays query statistics, route statistics, and more.

Unlike Laravel Debug Bar which renders in the page directly (thus unsuitable for APIs), Clockwork exposes the data out-of-band in two other places:

1. An optional Devtools extension:

[image: Image of Clockwork Devtools extension]

2. A dashboard at /clockwork:

[image: Image of Clockwork Dashboard]

The most basic installation just requires the package to be installed:

```sh
composer require itsgoingd/clockwork
```

Detailed instructions, the devtool extension, and further configuration details can be found in [the official readme](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork#installation)

Comment: While this probably isn't suitable for Laravel 4, it most definitely works great for recent Laravel versions!